# The best way to orginize classes / structure for web service and database handler

Tags: ios, web-services, design-patterns, database-design

Currently, I created 2 singleton classes one for processing services(e.g WebService.h) and other for handle accessing to database (e.g DatabaseHandler.h).

Do you think i should separate them into specific classes and then very easy to resuse? and if you have any other structure / pattern to apply this case please guide me.

Regards,
Jony

Comment: What was the reason you made them Singletons?

Comment: Do you mean just using static methods enough? I don't have much experience in designing. please guide.

Comment: You said you made 2 classes singletons. I wondered why.

Answer (score 0):

The webservice class should invoke the database broker if the user calls a data persistence action from the web api like GET, PUT, DELETE, etc. So i would tier the structure as follows:

```
DatabaseHandler(){
   // plain old db handler
}

CustomDatabaseHandler extends DatabaseHandler(){
   // now we extend the main instance to provide
   // more scalability and room
   // for custom logic overrides
}

$dbh = new CustomDatabaseHandler()

WebService($dbh){
  this.db = $dbh

  func create(){ 
    // do stuff here
    this.db.create()
  }

  func read(){ 
    // do stuff here
    this.db.read()
  }
}
```